# Special characters not displaying properly

Tags: html, ascii, bootstrap-modal, special-characters, html-entities

I'm using bootstrap 4 modal popup window - its using × for close icon, but for me its displaying as special characters like i marked in picture.

[image: bootstrap-modal]

Also i'm using utf-8 format in head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What `x` is used in the `HTML`?

Comment: &times; is used in html

Comment: Check how your editor is saving files. It wants to be set to `UTF-8`.